# Splunk Regex field extraction

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I want to extract a certain part of a string, for instance:

Input

```
\\host1\teams\team1\bla\bla\bla
\\host1\teams\team2\bla\bla
\\host1\teams\team3\bla
\\host1\teams\team4
```

Output

```
team1
team2
team3
team4
```

I have a Regular Expression that works on Regex101.com, however, when I take it to Splunk, it returns this error `Regex: missing terminating ] for character class` and I can't .

The Regex is:

```
(^\\\\host1\\teams\\)(?P<Team>[^\\]+)
```

Example data:

`"\\host1\teams\team1","abc123","def678"`

**Update**:

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/c9Lqh6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the struggles with Splunk's `rex` command is getting the escaping right.  It looks like Splunk is interpreting `"[^\\]"` as `"[^\]"` so it thinks the brackets aren't matched.  Experiment with additional backslashes or try `(^\\\\host1\\teams\\)(?P<Team>[\w]+)`.